# What is the difference between object and object[] in java

Tags: java, object

So i wrote a method that accepts any java object and i figured out that

```
public void mymethod(Object javaobject) {
}
```

works, but with

```
public void mymethod(Object[] javaobject) {
}
```

Eclipse trows an error

```
The method mymethod(Object[]) in the type myClass is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
```

So my question is, where is the difference between these two types ?

Comment: One of them is an array.

Comment: One is an instance of class Object but other is an array that allows you store the objects of class Object.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, the difference is that `Object` is a single object whereas `Object[]` is an array (multiple or collection) of indexed objects.

For example you could have an object that contains a string like

```
Object obj = "Hello";
```

or you could have an array of strings like

```
Object[] objArray = new Object[2];
objArray[0] = "Hello,";
objArray[1] = " world!";
```

So, `obj` is one Object. Whereas, `objArray` is an array that contains multiple objects indexed starting with 0. Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

An array is-a an `Object`, but one `Object` is not (necessarily) an array of `Object`(s). You could make your method take varargs,

```
public void mymethod(Object... javaobject) {
    // ...
}
```

Then it would work like an array (that is `javaobject` is an array) in both cases (called with one, or more, `Object`(s)).